# How to set the name of the database through a NodeJs API call

Tags: node.js, azure-sql-database

I have my sql server present at azure portal (basically I am using mssql) and I am trying to create a new database using NodeJs API call

basically my API looks like this `"http://localhost:9000/api/dbcreation/test/customer"` where my controller name is dbcreation, test is my database name where the store procedure present to create a new database and customer is my new database name.

Below is the model code which is called by the dbcreation controller to execute the query and @dbname value is the new database name (customer) which I am trying to fetch from the API

```
exports.get = async function (customerdb, dbname){
        var param_list = [];
        param_list.push({
            "param_name": "dbname",
            "param_type": "string",
            "param_value": dbname
        });
    var query = `exec p_dbCreation @dbname`;
    return db.sqldb.execute_read_query(query, customerdb, param_list);
}
```

And below is my stored procedure code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_dbCreation] @database_name nvarchar(30)
AS
CREATE DATABASE [@database_name] (EDITION = 'Standard', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ELASTIC_POOL (name = [xxxxx]), MAXSIZE = 250 GB) WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
GO
```

when I call the api the call is getting executed successfully but the database is getting created with the name @database_name it is not fetching the parameter value which I passed. Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: Hi @vignesh ramesh, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: Hi @JosephXu Thank you so much for your response it completely works fine now from your solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is casued by your T-SQL script. We need to dynamically splice the SQL statement and then execute it. The script should be as follows:

```sql
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_dbCreation] @database_name nvarchar(30) 
AS

declare @sql nvarchar(2000)

set @sql='CREATE DATABASE '+@database_name+'(EDITION = ''Standard'', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ELASTIC_POOL (name = [xxxxx]), MAXSIZE = 250 GB) WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;'
BEGIN
EXEC(@sql)
END
```